# Some problems with GetCreationTime function

Tags: c#, file

I have jpg file with date of creation: 04/29/2014

In C# when I write

```
DateTime dt = File.GetCreationTime("C:\\Users\\First\\Desktop\\1.jpg");
```

I have dt as 01/01/1601. Can somebody explain me why does it happen?

Comment: Have you checked the file exists at that exact location ?

Comment: It is `GetCreationTime` not `GetCreatedTime` by the way.

Comment: `File.GetCreationTime(string path)` is method to get created date of that file

Comment: @ВадимХадкевич, Try it again with `File.Exists(path)`.

Comment: M. Nasser Javaid, yeah, i've been mistaken

Comment: Orel Eraki, one second

Answer (score 3):

That means that file does not exist.

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> If the file described in the path parameter does not exist, this
>   method returns 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated
>   Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

Double check your path.